# How can I increment an integer field in a SQL Server database table only when another field changes value?

Tags: sql-server

I have an integer field (essentially a counter) called PID in a sql server table called Projects that I want to increment only when the value of another field changes (Task).  Initially PID=1 for all rows.  The following query (which I got from one of your answers elsewhere) does exactly what I want but I need to update my table with the result and that I cannot figure out.

```
SELECT Task,
  dense_rank() over(order by Task)  PID
FROM dbo.Projects;
```

If I do something like

```
Update Projects
SET Projects.PID =(SELECT Task,
  dense_rank() over(order by Task)  PID
FROM dbo.Projects);
```

I get "The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns."  How can I update my table with a query that gives me what I want?

This is the table design:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Projects]
( 
    [PID] [int] NULL
    , [TID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , [Project] [nvarchar](127) NOT NULL
    , [Task] [nvarchar](127) NOT NULL
    , [Dollars] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL
    , [TaskLead] [nvarchar](127) NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

I populate the table with

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Projects(Project, Task, Dollars, TaskLead) 
SELECT Project + ' ' + ProjectDescription, Task + ' ' + TaskDescription, Dollars, TaskLead 
FROM TM1_1 
ORDER BY Project ASC, Task ASC;
```

E.g. data:

```
PID     TID     Project     Task 
1       1       Prj1        Tsk11 
1       2       Prj1        Tsk12 
2       1       Prj2        Tsk21
```

I want to update the table such that all projects that are the same have the same PID. I am now trying:

```
use mbt_tm1; 
;WITH cteRank AS (
     SELECT PID, DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY Project ORDER BY Project ASC) AS Calculated_Rank 
    FROM Projects ) 
UPDATE cteRank 
SET PID = Calculated_Rank
```

Comment: You'll need to be clearer about what you actually want. Do you want the `PID` column to be the `dense_rank()` of it's `Task`, compared to other `Task`s? Note that this number will go up/down based on the sort order of the `Task` column.

Comment: I only know that the query with dense_rank worked.  What I want is to update my table such that I get, e.g.,

Comment: E.g.,
PID   TID   Project   Task
1     1     Prj1      Tsk11
1     2     Prj1      Tsk12
2     1     Prj2      Tsk21
and so on.  I get the Prj's and Tsk's from another source.  The I need to add the PID and TID according to this pattern.  I am not attached to dense_rank.  I only know that it did what I want when I used it in a query.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked:

```
;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT PID,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (
         ORDER BY Project ASC) AS Calculated_Rank
   FROM Projects
)
UPDATE cte SET PID = Calculated_Rank
```

It transformed a query that showed the result, namely:

```
SELECT Project,
  dense_rank() over(order by Project)  PID
FROM dbo.Projects;
```

into one that actually updated the table.  Thank you so much for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You have to return only one value from the inner query and you're looking for a rank:

```
Update Projects
SET Projects.PID = X.Calculated_Rank
FROM Project P
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT P1.PID, DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY P1.Project ORDER BY P1.Project ASC) AS Calculated_Rank 
    FROM Projects P1) X
ON X.PID = P.PID
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, I get:
"Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated."
I think I need a different approach, but I am not sure what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your exact question, perhaps this would work?

```
Update Projects
SET Projects.PID = dense_rank() over(order by Task);
```

To help with your question, I've put together a little sample that I think shows what you are asking.  If this does not reflect your environment, please add details to your question.

```
CREATE TABLE Projects 
(
    ProjectID INT
    , Task INT
    , PID INT
);
GO

INSERT INTO Projects (ProjectID, Task, PID) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Projects (ProjectID, Task, PID) VALUES (2, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO Projects (ProjectID, Task, PID) VALUES (3, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO Projects (ProjectID, Task, PID) VALUES (4, 2, 1);

UPDATE Projects
SET Projects.PID = (
    SELECT MAX(PID) + 1
    FROM Projects p 
    WHERE P.Task = Projects.Task
);

SELECT *
FROM Projects;
```

**[EDIT # 2]**

Unless I am misunderstanding your requirements, this seems a simple way to update the PID for all associated projects:

```
UPDATE Projects
SET PID = (SELECT MAX(PID) FROM Projects P WHERE P.Project = Projects.Project);
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry to say but your question is very unclear. yet the original SELECT query you told is working for you and you want to use it for update i see that update is wrong.
correct update syntex would be something like this.

**update PID in table with new Rank where Task is matching.**

```
    UPDATE  t1 SET t1.Projects.PID = t2.pid
    FROM Projects t1
    JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT Task ,DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Task ) PID
        FROM   Projects
    )t2
    ON t1.Task=t2.task
```

**EDIT:-1**
this query is to get the output as you explained and shown in example.

no need to use CTE.

```
    set nocount on
    declare @prj table
    (
        pid     int null
        ,tid    int null
        ,prj    sysname
        ,tsk    sysname

    )
    insert into @prj (prj,tsk)
    select 'prj1','tsk11' 
    union all select 'prj1','tsk12' 
    union all select 'prj2','tsk21'
    union all select 'prj2','tsk22'

    update t1 set t1.pID=t2.pID, t1.tID=t2.tID
    from @prj t1
    join
    (

        select  dense_RANK() over (order by prj) as pID
                ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by prj order by prj,tsk) as tID
                ,prj,tsk
        from @prj
    )t2
        on t1.prj=t2.prj and t1.tsk=t2.tsk

    select * from @prj
```

[image]

Comment: My situation is exactly as in http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1020106-338-1.aspx but what worked for that person is not working for me.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: updated the query as you want the answer. no need for CTE. see the code under Edit-1.

Comment: CTE seemed to work very well.  Is there a reason not to use it?

Comment: nothing wrong, just saying, if the query can be written w/o it you should go for it.